# How do I change the cassette tape data (baud) rate on MSX machines?

Tags: cassette-tape, msx

The MSX Resource Center Wiki [mentions](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Data_Recorder_connector) that MSX machines can save and load at either 1200 or 2400 bps or baud. But it doesn't mention how to change this setting.

So how do I change that rate? Is it consistent between all MSX machines? Do all MSX machines, back to the earliest MSX1 machines, have this capability? Does the setting need to be changed for load, or does that auto-detect?

Answer (score 7):

You can set the baud rate for a single save with the optional *baudrate* parameter (`1`=1200 or `2`=2400) to the `CSAVE "<filename>"[,<baudrate>]` command. You can set the default with the [SCREEN command](https://www.msx.org/wiki/SCREEN): `SCREEN <DisplayMode>,<SpriteSize>,<Keyclick>,<BaudRate>,<PrinterType>,<InterlaceMode>`.

For reading, the matching data rate is [automatically chosen](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalDataBook/page/n86/mode/1up):

> Note that when reading cassette, the baud rate is automatically determined, so that users do not need to know the baud rate the cassette is written.

Comment: It is, after all, intuitively obvious to the most casual observer that you'd use the `screen` command to set the baud rate for loading/saving files! ;-)

Comment: “Note that when reading cassette, the baud rate is automatically determined, so that users do not need to know the baud rate the cassette is written.” — [MSX Technical Data Book](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalDataBook/page/n86/mode/1up) (Sony, 1984) - p.84

Comment: @scruss Thanks for finding that! I've updated the answer to include the reference and quote.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Right! After all, it was also obviously intuitive to you that it's used for key click and printer settings as well, right? :-)

Comment: @cjs you're welcome! Cassette input pretty much has to be self-clocking because of the huge variation in speed in tape mechanisms. Agreeing that `SCREEN` is a wacky place to put this, but maybe Keyclick does stuff with timer settings and - like almost everything in retrocomputing - it seemed like a good idea at the time to jam in cassette baud rate too.

Comment: @cjs: If we're being serious for a moment, historically it actually does kind of make sense. Early on, the only system setting of note was screen resolution. So (on a fair number of systems, not just the MSX), when they had other semi-persistent system settings to do, "screen" honestly did seem like a reasonable place to put them. And as long as you ignore the name, it actually did kind of make sense.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, I too thought that might have been the way it worked out, but even in the [inital MSX1 spec](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalHandbookBySony/page/n86/mode/1up) the command is  `SCREEN [<mode>][,<sprite size>][,<key click switch>][,<cassette baud rate>][,<printer option>]`. So it was overloaded in this way from the start.

Comment: @cjs: I'd expect that if you look at the MSX spec in isolation. I was thinking in slightly broader terms--by the time the MSX came out, Microsoft had included a `screen` command in a fair number of previous BASIC interpreters (e.g., GW-BASIC). Offhand, I'm not sure when Microsoft first used the `screen` command, but it was well known before the MSX standard was written (and I'm pretty sure a few versions had already accreted functionality that wasn't related to the actual screen before then, though I don't remember that with certainty).

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's a good point, but I'd think that when you're introducing a new BASIC with incompatible commands woud be the perfect time to re-work your command names as well. (`SCREEN` was not really compatible because the screen numbers were specific to the TMS9918 VDP. And other commands lost some compatibility, such as `COLOR` in the European default screen mode 0. Not to mention all the new commands and functions such as `BASE`, `VPEEK`, `VDP()`, etc.)

Comment: My feeling, from reading and comparing the source code of various MS-BASICs from various eras, is that with every new version of MS-BASIC they were trying to minimise changes, probably due to the testing cost. (I've never seen signs of a good automated testing suite for MS-BASICs.)

Comment: @cjs: I think MS was happy to do whatever vendors would pay for. But for a vendor, BASIC was a necessity, not a competitive advantage. Users chose computers based on hardware features, not the BASIC provided. So vendors mostly got nearly the cheapest port they could, even if that meant user access to whizzy hardware was almost exclusively via peek and poke (or assembly language, etc.)